# sql tasks for beginners

Tags: sql, oracle, task

I have 3 questions, that I could not resolve.
Exists 2 tables

```
CREATE TABLE T_DEPARTMENT
(
  ID    NUMBER,
  NAME  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)

CREATE TABLE T_EMPLOYEE
(
  ID             NUMBER,
  DEPARTMENT_ID  NUMBER,
  CHIEF_ID       NUMBER,
  NAME           VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  SALARY         NUMBER
)
```

Questions:

1 -  Get the names of departments and the number of employees in them, the number of employees exceeds 20 people

2 - Display the percentage of consumption of the overall budget by departments

3 - Find chief salaries that are less than 10% higher than the employee with a maximum salary in that department.

I tries these, all are incorrect:

1.

```
select id from t_employee group by id having count(*) <= 20
```

2.

```
select sum (salary) from t_employee group by id
```

3.

```
select e1.name from t_employee e1, t_employee e2 where e2.id = e1.chief_id and e1.salary < e2.salary*0.1 all is uncorrect
```

Comment: Would suggest to try some queries and if you get any errors please update the question.

Comment: Side note. It's always a good idea for those DDLs you've provided to be accompanied by `insert` statements to populate tables with data, and provide mock-up of expected output.

Comment: 1 - select id  from t_employee  group by id having count(*) <= 20

2- select sum (salary) from t_employee group by id;

3 - select e1.name from t_employee e1, t_employee e2 where e2.id = e1.chief_id  and e1.salary < e2.salary*0.1                                                    all is uncorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok for first part use this query:

```
select 
t1.name,
count(t1.name) as EmployeesCount,
case when count(t1.name)>20 then 'True' else 'False' end as moreThan20 
from 
T_DEPARTMENT t1,
T_EMPLOYEE t2 
where 
t1.id = t2.department_id 
group by t1.name;
```

for second this:

```
select 
name,
salary,
(salary * 100) / (select sum(salary) from hatest2)  as percentage
from 
T_EMPLOYEE
group by salary;
```

and for the last i suppose you got a table names as T_CHIEF and this select show you the personnel's which are not chief:

```
select 
t2.name  
from 
T_CHIEF t1,
T_EMPLOYEE t2 
where 
t1.id = t2.chief_id and 
t2.salary < (select max(salary) * 0.1 from T_EMPLOYEE where CHIEF_ID not in(select id from T_CHIEF)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> IN sql server

1>

```
select a.id,a.name from T_DEPARTMENT a join T_EMPLOYEE b on a.ID=b.DEPARTMENT_ID group by a.id having count(*) >=20
```

2>

```
Select salary, (SUM(salary)* 100 / (Select Count(*) from T_EMPLOYEE)) as percentage_sal
    From T_EMPLOYEE
    Group By salary
```

3>

```
select e1.name  from T_DEPARTMENT e1, T_EMPLOYEE e2 where e2.id = e1.chief_id and e1.salary < e2.salary*0.1`
```

Comment: 1 - ORA-00979: GROUP BY

Comment: try to add some sample data to the tables,as the questions are unclear to answer exactly?

Comment: it executes on sql-server i no idea on oracle ?